# How to build arXiv-metadata-snapshot using dump of arxiv metadata?

Tags: research, research-papers

after dumping all the metadata i have three files:

```
arxiv-metadata-oai.json  
authors-parsed.json  
internal-citations.json
```

Sample of `arxiv-metadata-oai.json`:

```
{
  "id": "0704.0081",
  "submitter": "Valeriy Tolstoy",
  "authors": "V.N. Tolstoy (INP, Moscow State University)",
  "title": "Quantum Deformations of Relativistic Symmetries",
  "comments": "10 pages. Invited talk at the XXII Max Born Symposium \"Quantum, Super\n  and Twistors\", September 27-29, 2006, Wroclaw (Poland), in honour of Jerzy\n  Lukierski.",
  "journal-ref": null,
  "doi": null,
  "abstract": "  We discussed quantum deformations of D=4 Lorentz and Poincare algebras. In\nthe case of Poincare algebra it is shown that almost all classical r-matrices\nof S. Zakrzewski classification correspond to twisted deformations of Abelian\nand Jordanian types. A part of twists corresponding to the r-matrices of\nZakrzewski classification are given in explicit form.\n",
  "report-no": null,
  "categories": [
    "math.QA hep-th math-ph math.MP math.RT"
  ],
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ]
}
```

Sample of `internal-citations.json`:

```
{
  "0704.0081": [
    "hep-th/0301033",
    "math/0701079",
    "hep-th/0604146",
    "math/0402433",
    "math/0010190",
    "0704.0081"
  ]
}
```

Sample of `authors-parsed.json`:

```
{
  "0704.0081": [
    [
      "Tolstoy",
      "V. N.",
      "",
      "INP, Moscow State University"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I need to create snapshot file like [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/Cornell-University/arxiv/data) with `update_date` and `versions`. So after digging some time i realized that some fields are missing.

The most wanted field is update_date. How to get it from the dump?

Comment: It sounds like a XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Is there a reason not to simply download the metadata from the link you mention at the end of your question? The data seem to be updated on a regular basis, last update was 3 days ago.

Comment: I completely agree with you but i need to build my own structure of data based on meta and full texts. For now i can't find where pub_date exist